# How to Group Similar Rows in Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

| DATE | ADRESS |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-09-02 | ENGLAND |
| 2010-09-03 | ENGLAND |
| 2010-09-04 | ENGLAND |
| 2010-09-05 | ENGLAND |
| 2010-09-06 | GERMANY |
| 2010-09-07 | GERMANY |
| 2010-09-08 | GERMANY |
| 2011-09-03 | ENGLAND |
| 2012-09-02 | ENGLAND |
| 2013-09-03 | ENGLAND |

I have a table like this and what I want to do, I want the result I want to get, how can I do it?

| DATE | ADRESS |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-09-02 - 2010-09-05 | ENGLAND |
| 2010-09-06 - 2010-09-08 | GERMANY |
| 2011-09-03 - 2013-09-03 | ENGLAND |

Comment: I'm working in MSSQL

Comment: that is a simple gaps and island problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *gaps and islands* problem here, you could use the difference between two row_numbers approach to solving it, try the following:

```
select concat_ws(' - ', min([date]), max([date])) as [date],
       address
from
(
  select *,
   row_number() over (order by date) -
   row_number() over (partition by address order by [date]) grp
  from table_name
) t
group by address, grp
order by min([date])
```

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/brGi9IIS)

Comment: +1 for introducing the term *gaps and islands* as something I can remember to look up later and help identify when I see a similar use case. Normally I may have gone straight to building a temp table with an inspection counter...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(DATE), ' - ', MAX(DATE)), ADRESS
    FROM tablename GROUP BY ADRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned before this is a gaps and islands problem.

This is an other way to solve it :

```
with cte as (
  select *, lag(ADRESS, 1, ADRESS) over(order by id) as lag_ADRESS
  from ( select row_number() over() as id, t.* from mytable t) s
  ORDER BY id
),
cte2 as (
  select *, sum(case when ADRESS = lag_ADRESS then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
  from cte
)
select ADRESS, concat(min(DATE),' - ', max(Date)) as ADRESS
from cte2
group by ADRESS, grp
```

Lag() is a window function that allows you to look back a number of rows and access data of that row from the current row.

Then we check by a `CASE WHEN` clause where the records have been broken.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/V1zxSaQH)